# Problems creating data frame in R based on results from a SOAP request (RCurl)

Tags: r, xpath, soap, rcurl

I have retrieved XML data using a SOAP request (via RCurl). The data contains a list of 10 legal judgements, for I would like to extract two pieces of information ("Entscheidungsart" and "Gericht") and put them into a data frame.

Unfortunately, the XPaths do not seem to work for me, resulting in an empty data frame.

```
  library(RCurl)   headerFields =
    c(Accept = "text/xml",
      Accept = "multipart/*",
      'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
      SOAPAction = "http://ris.bka.gv.at/ogd/V2_5/SearchDocuments")   
##############
body <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <SearchDocuments xmlns="http://ris.bka.gv.at/ogd/V2_5">
          <query>
            <Suche>
            <Judikatur>
              <Dokumenttyp>
                <SucheInRechtssaetzen>0</SucheInRechtssaetzen>
                <SucheInEntscheidungstexten>1</SucheInEntscheidungstexten>
              </Dokumenttyp>
              <Vfgh>
                <Entscheidungsart>Undefined</Entscheidungsart>
                <Index>*</Index>
                <Sammlungsnummer>*</Sammlungsnummer>
                <Sortierung xsi:type="VfghSortExpression">
                  <SortDirection>Ascending</SortDirection>
                  <SortedByColumn>Datum</SortedByColumn>
                </Sortierung>
              </Vfgh>
              <ImRisSeit>Undefined</ImRisSeit>
              <DokumenteProSeite>Ten</DokumenteProSeite>
              <Seitennummer>1</Seitennummer>
            </Judikatur>
            </Suche>
          </query>
        </SearchDocuments>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>'   
##############
reader = basicTextGatherer()   
curlPerform(url = "https://data.bka.gv.at/ris/ogd/v2.5/ogdrisservice.asmx",
              httpheader = headerFields,
              postfields = body, 
              writefunction = reader$update) 
##############
doc <- xmlParse(reader$value())   
root <- xmlRoot(doc)   
data = data.frame(Entscheidungsart = xpathSApply(doc,"//Entscheidungsart", xmlValue),
                    Gericht = xpathSApply(doc,"//Gericht", xmlValue))
```

Comment: `library(xml2); reader$value() %>% read_xml() %>% {data.frame(Entscheidungsart = xml_find_all(., '//d1:Entscheidungsart') %>% xml_text(), Gericht = xml_find_all(., '//d1:Gericht') %>% xml_text())}`

Comment: Thank you very much alistaire. This has worked for me. If I may ask you one more thing: reader$value() contains nodes called <Urls> with multiple children called <ContentUrl>. Is it possible to extract only the the URLs that refer to a XML (and ignore URLs to html, pdf, or rtf)? Thank you again - I very much appreciate that you took the time to look into my question!

Comment: Just found out how to do it: xml_find_all(., '//d1:Urls/d1:ContentUrl[d1:DataType/text() = "Xml"]/d1:Url'). Thank you again alistaire for your help.